# Get last word inside table cell?

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri, scraper

I want to scrape data from a table with Ruby and Nokogiri.

There are a lot of `<td>` elements, but I only need the country which is just text after a `<br>` element. The problem is, the `<td>` elements differ. Sometimes there is more than just the country.

For example:

```
<td><a href="#">Title1</a><br>USA</td>
<td><a href="#">Title2</a><br>Michael Powell<br>UK</td>
<td><a href="#">Title3</a><br>Leopold Lindtberg<br>Ralph Meeker<br>Switzerland</td>
```

I want to address the element before the closing `</td>` tag because the country is always the last element.

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't see any code showing you've attempted to solve the problem. Please post some.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use this:

```
require 'awesome_print'
require 'nokogiri'

html = '
<td><a href="#">Title1</a><br>USA</td>
<td><a href="#">Title2</a><br>Michael Powell<br>UK</td>
<td><a href="#">Title3</a><br>Leopold Lindtberg<br>Ralph Meeker<br>Switzerland</td>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
ap doc.search('td').map{ |td| td.search('text()').last.text }

[
    [0] "USA",
    [1] "UK",
    [2] "Switzerland"
]
```

The problem is that your HTML being parsed won't have rows of `<td>` tags, so you'll have to locate the ones you want to parse. Instead, they'll be interspersed between `<tr>` tags, and maybe even different `<table>` tags. Because your HTML sample doesn't show the true structure of the document, I can't help you more.

Comment: Or with more XPath and less Ruby: `doc.search('//td/text()[last()]').map(&:text) #=> ["USA", "UK", "Switzerland"]`

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of different solutions. Another solution using only the standard library is to substring out the things you dont want.

```
node_string = <<-STRING
  <td><a href="#">Title1</a><br>USA</td>
  <td><a href="#">Title2</a><br>Michael Powell<br>UK</td>
  <td><a href="#">Title3</a><br>Leopold Lindtberg<br>Ralph Meeker<br>Switzerland</td>
STRING
node_string.split("<td>").collect do |str| 
  last_str = str.split("<br>").last
  last_str.gsub(/[\n,\<\/td\>]/,'') unless last_str.nil?
end.compact
```